# Sending Xcode data to JSON

Tags: objective-c, json

I am fairly new to xcode but I currently have an app that will send data to a sql database but I know it has to go through JSON first.

Say my app is simply a text box where a user enters a name and submits. How would I turn that data into JSON? What would the syntax look like?

Comment: If you Google "iOS JSON" you will get thousands of hits.  (Don't look for "Xcode", since that's the IDE, not the language or operating system.)

Comment: (The syntax would look like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_basic_syntax.htm).)

Comment: You don't send Xcode data to JSON. You send app data (written in whatever language you chose for your app) to a server. The data may happen to be formatted as JSON.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for clearing that up! I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/

If you are sending the data through a network, then look into AFNetworking.

(added in response to a comment)

```
NSString *jsonFromObject(id object)
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: object options: 0 error: &error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error creating json string: %@", error);
    }
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData: jsonData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```